# Snowpack config only build modules from package.json

Tags: javascript, node-modules, snowpack

I am new to Snowpack (and frontend build tools in general), but I am looking for a solution to use my Node modules inside my client-side Javascript (using ESM syntax), and the idea of Snowpack bundling my modules in separate JS-files attracts me. This is my file structure:

```
/node_modules
/assets
  /css
  /js
  /img
  /lib
/views

*.config.js
package.json
```

I am interested in Snowpacks ability to build only my Node modules that I personally installed (what's inside my `package.json`) for use in the browser, and leave the rest of my application alone. I want Snowpack to put my files in the `/assets/lib` directory, but any configuration I try, it just doesn't work out. Snowpack takes my entire project folder, builds any module it finds, and puts it all inside my `/assets/lib` directory. With my limited knowledge of Snowpacks configuration, I've created this as my `snowpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  buildOptions: {
    out: './assets/lib',
    baseUrl: './'
  },
};
```

If anyone with a little more experience in Snowpack than me could help me out with what I'm doing wrong here, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the root folder in snowpack.config.js it will only build the contents of that folder to the out folder specified in buildOptions.

```
module.exports = {
    root: './assets/lib',
    buildOptions: {
        out: './assets/dist'
    },
};
```